# Analytical description of rotation operator

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, analytic-geometry, rotations

Let $\delta$ be the rotation with center $(1,2)$, that maps the point $(-1,3)$ to the point $(3,3)$.

(a) Describe $\delta$ analytically and determine the rotation angle.

(b) Let $g$ be the line with equation $x-3y-10=0$. Calculate an equation of the line $\delta (g)$.

(c) Let $\tau$ be the translation that maps $(-1,3)$ to $(3,3)$. What kind of transformation is $\tau\circ\delta$ ?

$$$$

For (a) do we have to write it in the form $\delta (x)=Ax$ ? To find the matrix do we have to shift the center to the origin first?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

In (c) do we have to calculate $\tau$ ? Or is the composition of a translation and a rotation always a specific transformation?

In this case the rotation $\delta$ and the translation $\tau$ map both the point $(-1,3)$ to $(3,3)$.

Is this important?

Comment: Since the center is $(1,2),$ you need $\delta(x)-(1,2) = A(x-(1,2)). \qquad$

Comment: Ah yes! Then we use that $\delta ((-1,3))=(3,3)$, right? But is this condition enough to get the matrix $A$ ? @MichaelHardy

Comment: You need $A((-1,3)^\top - (1,2)^\top) = ((3,3)^\top - (1,2)^\top),$ so $A(-2,1)^\top = (2,1)^\top.$ But notice that $A$ must not only satisfy that, but must also be a rotation matrix. $\qquad$

Comment: The rotation matrix is of the form $A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}$, right? So we get $$A\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}-\cos \theta  -\sin \theta \\ -2\sin \theta + \cos \theta \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ So we get the system \begin{align*}-\cos \theta  -\sin \theta=&2 \\ -2\sin \theta + \cos \theta =&1\end{align*} And we get $\sin \theta=-1 \Rightarrow \theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$. @MichaelHardy

Comment: Then we get the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and so the analytic description of the rotation is $$\delta(x)-\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x-\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}$$ Is that correct? @MichaelHardy

Comment: For (b) : We take two points of the line find their images and calculate the line through these points, right? The points $(10,0)$ and $(13,1)$ are on $g$. We have that $\delta \left (\begin{pmatrix}10 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right )=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ -7\end{pmatrix}$ and $\delta \left (\begin{pmatrix}13 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right )=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ -10\end{pmatrix}$.  
The line through $(-1, -7)$ and $(0,-10)$ is $$\delta (g): y-(-10)=\frac{-10-(-7)}{0-(-1)}(x-0) \Rightarrow y+10=\frac{-10+7}{1}x\Rightarrow 3x+y+10=0$$ Is that correct? @MichaelHardy

Comment: Could you give me a hint for (c) ? @MichaelHardy

Comment: $$
\left[ \begin{array}{rr} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{r} -2 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{r} -2\cos\theta-\sin\theta \\ -2\sin\theta+\cos\theta \end{array} \right]
$$

Comment: Remember how matrix multiplication is defined: $$ \left[ \begin{array}{c} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} ax+by \\ cx+dy \end{array} \right] $$

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot the 2, right? So we get the system \begin{align*}-2\cos \theta  -\sin \theta=&2 \\ -2\sin \theta + \cos \theta =&1\end{align*} So we get $\sin \theta=-\frac{4}{5}$, right? @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've essentially answered this in comments, here it is for the record:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{rr} -3/5 & 4/5 \\ -4/5 & -3/5 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{r} -2 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{r} 2 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]
$$

So $\cos\theta = \dfrac{-3}5$  and $\sin\theta = \dfrac{-4}5.$

Comment: The angle of rotation is then \begin{equation*}\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{\dfrac{-4}5}{\dfrac{-3}5} \Rightarrow \tan \theta=\frac{4}{3} \Rightarrow \theta=\arctan \left (\frac{4}{3}\right )\approx 53.13^{\circ}\end{equation*} right?

Comment: Could you give me a hint for question (c) ?

Comment: In (c) do we have to calculate $\tau$ ? Or is the composition of a translation and a rotation always a specific transformation?

Comment: @MaryStar : A rotation followed by a translation is another rotation, through the same angle, but with a different center. The center is the one fixed point of the transformation. Here is the rotation centered at $[1,\,\,2]^T$ that you described.
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{r} x \\ y \end{array} \right] \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{rr} -3/5 & 4/5 \\ -4/5 & -3/5 \end{array} \right]\left( \left[ \begin{array}{r} x \\ y \end{array} \right] - \left[ \begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right] \right) + \left[ \begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right]
$$

Comment: @MaryStar : Now let a translation follow that:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{r} x \\ y \end{array} \right] \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{rr} -3/5 & 4/5 \\ -4/5 & -3/5 \end{array} \right]\left( \left[ \begin{array}{r} x \\ y \end{array} \right] - \left[ \begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right] \right) + \left[ \begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right] + \left[ \begin{array}{r} 4 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]
$$ Since you're looking for a fixed point, put an "equals" sign where the arrow is and then solve for $x$ and $y.$ You get $x=3, y=1. \qquad$

Comment: The composition then is $$ \left[ \begin{array}{r} x \\ y \end{array} \right] \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{rr} -3/5 & 4/5 \\ -4/5 & -3/5 \end{array} \right]\left( \left[ \begin{array}{r} x \\ y \end{array} \right] - \left[ \begin{array}{r} 3 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] \right) + \left[ \begin{array}{r} 3 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] $$

Comment: How did you get $\begin{pmatrix}4\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Ah it isthe difference between the mapped point $(3,3)$and the original point $(-1,3)$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar : Yes. $\qquad$

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much!! :-)